# How to compare current Hours with a hour string JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have attribute string Time:"10:50" response in JavaScript.
How to compare only hour of string with hour of system.
E.g: if 10=10 then run code in function.
Please help. thanks

Comment: give more information with code so we can understand what you are saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the string into a date object and use the getHours() function on the date object. something like

```
//in the oldDate, pass the string as params to the date constructor
let oldDate = new Date("date string") 
//construct this one without a parameter and it will use the system time
let systemDate = new Date()

if(oldDate.getHours() == systemDate.getHours())
```

But if you are quite certain that the response is of the form `"10:50"` then this will be the better option

```
let time = "10:50"
let h = parseInt(time.split(":")[0])

let systemDate = new Date()
if(h == systemDate.getHours())
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Date object: `let dateTime = new Date();`
2. Get the current hour: `let hour = dateTime.getHours();`
3. Compare it with your desired object.